# Why does my Python regex not work as expected when including a forward slash?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a Python issue when I include a not / in my regex.

In the following example I only want to find a match if the string sitting in the first word boundary starts with a digit AND there isn't a `/` at any point afterwards.

Why does the following regex return `1ab` as a group value?  I was hoping it wouldn't find a match at all:

```
text = "1ab/"
regex = r"\b(\d[^/]*?)\b"
```

Whereas:

```
text = "1abc"
regex = r"\b(\d[^c]*?)\b"
```

does not return any match, which is the outcome I want for the `/` scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Roy

Comment: You get `1ab` as a group value because there is a word boundary between `b` and `/`

Comment: The second part there is no match, as the pattern first matches a digit, and any char except `c`. It can not match c at the end and backtracks but can not match the word boundary anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it. Yet the slash is not alphanumerical and thus cannot be inside word . Therefore it makes no sense to match or prohibit it start and the end of the word. You have to place "not slash" sub-expression `[^/]` after the end of word. And add a star `[^/]*` (which matches the sequence of non-slash symbols) to address the case when slashes occurs toward the end of the string rather than immediately after the end of the first word.

Since you target the first word and absence of slash until the very end of string adding symbols of the start end might help. Especially, if you are use `re.search`.  Resulting in

```
^[\W]*\b(\d\w*)\b[^/]*\Z
```

You can play with it using an online debugger such as https://regex101.com/r/uO27vU/2
to better understand the expression or tune it.

Above `^` is a start, `\Z` is the end of sting, `\W` is for "non-word" symbols, a `\w` is "word" symbol.

You can remove the first `\b` I kept it, as perhaps,  it would easier for you to understand with it.

---

The second expression that you tried excludes words ending with `c` but first does not. `^c` stands for any symbol but c and right after it you have `\b` which denotes the end of the word. Which reads please no "c"s at the end of the word.

Your first expression says pleas no slashes before the end of the word (sequence of alphanumeric) . Which is the case for you test.

Always use a debugger to get explanation of each symbol,test and
tune your expressions regex101.com/r/B6INGg/2

Note that the list of symbols in a word might be affected by flags. When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
r'\b(\d\w*?)\b(?!.*/)' (use flags=re.DOTALL with this or prepend (?s) to the regex)
```

`(?!.*/)` states that the rest of the input string does not contain a '/' character. If you don't want '/' to appear just as the next character, then use as the assertion `(?!/)`.